# How can I run a script during the installation of a conda package and not during conda build

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, conda

I am trying to create a conda package that simply runs a script when `conda install <package_name>` is called.
But I am unable to figure out how to run any command during the installation process of that package. All the commands that I am able to add run during the `conda build <pacakge_name>` process. It seems as if installation is simply copying the files and we do not have any access to running any scripts during the installation part of the process.
Is there any way to write a conda pacakge such that a script can be run during the installation of that package?

Comment: See the docs for information: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/link-scripts.html

Comment: @darthbith Thanks a lot! got it!